# Retrieving iframe contents after a form submitted to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with an iframe as its target, and I want to retrieve its contents after the form has been submitted.

The problem is if I do something like:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $('iframe').contents();
});
```

I get nothing because the form only submits after this. Is there any event that I can use AFTER the iframe received its content?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the load event of the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the load event of the iframe.

```
$("iframe").load(function(){
  var response = this.document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML;
  alert(response);
});
```